# AWK Script that Counts Instances of Numbers, for Each Section

Tags: for-loop, awk, while-loop

Perhaps AWK isn't the best coding language for the task I'm trying to use it on.  I'm familiar with Python, but I just love using AWK in cases like this.  Here's my coding problem.  I have a file that looks like this:

```
name1 0
name1 1
name1 0
name1 1
name2 0
name2 0
name3 1
name3 1
name3 1
name3 0
```

I'm trying to count the number of 0's and 1s for each of the different names (they go up to around 3000.)  So for example, I'd want to print the following in a new file

```
name1 2 2    #There are 2 ones and 2 zeros
name2 0 2    #There are 0 ones, and 2 zeros
name3 1 3    #There are 1 one, and 3 zeros
```

Counting the 0's and 1's is obvious, and I would use a simple if/else statement

```
awk '{
if (variable == false)
    while (
if ($2 == 0)
    a++;
else
    b++;
}'
```

How would I go about making sure that I am counting for each of the names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with `awk` arrays:

```
awk '{
m[$1,$2]++;a[$1]
}
END{
for(i in a) 
   print i, (m[i,"1"] ? m[i,"1"] : "0") , (m[i,"0"] ? m[i,"0"] : 0) 
}'  names
```

- The first array `m` is used to save field + number and use it later.
- The second is array `a` is to remember the first field.
- `(m[i"1"] ? m[i"1"] : "0") , (m[i"0"] ? m[i"0"] : 0)` is ternary operator, to use in case of not having anything in `m`.

Comment: When I run this, it seems like it isn't counting correctly as I just see 0 1, instead of the actual number of 0's and 1s that are seen for each name.

Comment: When I run it with your example I obtain this: `name1 2 2
name2 0 2
name3 3 1
`

Comment: My mistake (I was using a text file that had only one unique name each, so of course it wasn't counting anything.  Thanks!!!

Comment: If the answer was useful for you, consider to follow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

If your input is sorted as in your example, then with any awk:

```
$ awk '
    NR>1 && $1!=prev { print prev, cnt[1]+0, cnt[0]+0; delete cnt }
    { cnt[$2]++; prev=$1 }
    END { print prev, cnt[1]+0, cnt[0]+0 }
' file
name1 2 2
name2 0 2
name3 3 1
```

otherwise if the input is not sorted then with GNU awk for true multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$ awk '
    { cnt[$1][$2]++ }
    END{ for (key in cnt) print key, cnt[key][1]+0, cnt[key][0]+0 }
' file
name1 2 2
name2 0 2
name3 3 1
```

or with any awk:

```
$ awk '
    { cnt[$1,$2]++; keys[$1] }
    END { for (key in keys) print key, cnt[key,1]+0, cnt[key,0]+0 }
' file
name1 2 2
name2 0 2
name3 3 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy way to do this, simply by using parallel associative arrays as follows:

```
    $2 == 0 { zero[$1] += 1; one[$1] += 0 }
    $2 == 1 { zero[$1] += 0; one[$1] += 1 }
    END { for (key in zero) { print key" "one[key]" "zero[key] } }
```

This ignores *all* lines that don't have zero or one as the second field, and updates the parallel arrays correctly (i.e., adds the appropriate value to both arrays) to make post-processing easy.

The post-processing simply involves iterating over the keys of *one* of the arrays and printing out values from both. The correct updating mentioned in the previous paragraph ensures that every key will be in *both* arrays.